# Can not run steam on Linux Mint 18 (hanged at installing breakpad...)

Tags: drivers, wine, games, steam, amd-graphics

This is what I get when I try to run `steam` on my Linux Mint 18 system:

```
$ steam
Running Steam on linuxmint 18 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
```

I'm using an AMD graphics card with default mint drivers, because as we all know AMD does not support newest versions of Ubuntu/Mint with official drivers.

Also, I have installed wine, steam, steam-launcher and tried all the fixes with fonts, moving something in steam folders etc.

I tried ALL possible fixes I could find in the internet and yet I still get the error.

What I tried so far:

- installed wine
- installed fonts
- tried to move steam folders around
- tried to install amd proprietary drivers on mint 18, no way to get them working
- updated kernel
- modified steam.sh
- reinstalled steam like 20 times
- the "LD_PRELOAD" fix
- installed some libraries
- tried to run steam in nomodeset and modeset.radeon=1

All of these did nothing, and steam is not working
After some of the fixes it throws the X server problem, after some it throws the one mentioned above.

I have no idea what to do now, does anyone have any ideas?

@EDIT
Yesterday I have downloaded all -dev libraries using userscript.
This did not help

Comment: Are you following a specific guide?  Also how does xsession errors (`~/.xsession-errors`) and xorg log (`/var/log/Xorg*log` and/or `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg*log`) look?

Comment: xorg in var/log: [link](http://pastebin.com/vYu6xMu7) , xorg in local/share: [link] (http://pastebin.com/iUt3dVq4), xsession errors:  [link](http://pastebin.com/mUUe9xbA)

Comment: Also no, im not following any specific guide because all of them seem to provide just small answer in terminal that requires to do something or move something in steam folder

Comment: The important lines in xorg log are always errors `(EE)`, it might be useful to edit the question and add them.  The important one is that the acceleration method "galmor" cannot be loaded.  You could add a Device section to `xorg.conf` and change it to none.  But really, I would change the driver.  `xf86-video-amdgpu` is just too new,it fails **a lot** (for example now), mint should have a package with the old `xf86-video-ati` driver.

Comment: @grochmal I had both installed. I uninstalled xf86-video-amdgpu(in synaptics) is it the right way to do this or i should purge it or something?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `fglrx` driver isn't supported on linux mint 18 , it is not possible to install `steam`, you can get some informations about the prerequisites you need from [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux) or [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst15-9LINReleaseNotes.aspx)

[**Important information**](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_sarah_cinnamon.php)

> The AMD Catalyst (fglrx) drivers are not compatible with Xorg 1.18, which is the version used in Linux Mint 18.
>
> These drivers are proprietary and so their code is not available. AMD indicated they no longer wanted to support them and urged their customers to use open-source drivers instead.
>
> If you are using an ATI GPU in Linux Mint 18, the operating system will either select the Radeon or AMDGPU drivers for you, and these are installed by default.